# Where can I go to check for updates for the type of Flash Player Youtube uses?

Tags: flash-player

Sometimes 3 or more times a week Youtube doesn't work because Flash crashes which usually means it has been updated.  But I never get an update notification for Flash unless I restart my computer.  Where can I go to check whether my Flash Player is the latest; somewhere where it will tell me whether I have the latest version or not?  The official site doesn't let you know whether you need an update or not.   Also, how can I set-up a notification system that works without having to restart my computer daily to find out whether Flash has to be updated?

Win 7 Pro.
IE 9.

Comment: Youtube uses whatever Flash player you have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually check for Flash Player updates by using the **Flash Player Settings Manager**.

- Open the **Control Panel** and **search** for "`Flash`".
- **Click** `Flash Player` to open the **Flash Player Settings Manager**.

  [image: Flash Player]
- Go to the **Advanced** tab and **click** the `Check Now` button in the **Updates** section.

  [image: Check Now]
- You will be taken to Adobe's Flash Player [website](https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/) where you can compare your version of Flash Player to the latest version available for your platform.

  [image: screenshot]

Comment: So, I have the latest version but Dailymotion or Youtube gets a green screen when I try to play videos?  Why?

Comment: Try updating your graphics drivers. If that doesn't resolve the issue, then you can try [disabling hardware acceleration](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/help01.html). Alternatively, you could use [YouTube's HTML5 Video Player](https://www.youtube.com/html5).

Comment: Are any cons to the HTML5 player? Oh, it's in trials...and is there no way to set-up auto-notifications for updates?

Comment: Yeah... It is still experimental.

Comment: Where can I update my graphics drivers?

Answer (score 1):

youtube directions: http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=56115

Flash directions: http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer.html (currently version 11 but note that the url will bring up the latest).